# ListView dynamic with 3 textview and 1 radio button. it's possible?

Tags: java, android, listview, dynamic

I am trying to make a custom `ListView` with 3 `TextView`s and with 1 `RadioButton` for each row.

I add some info about a people and when i will save it, i want to show that info in a `ListView`.
I use a custom title in all activities so i can't extend `ListActivity` because my custom title and `Shared Preferences` dont will work.
I cant use arrays because my info it's dynamic. What i should do to implement this solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ListView` to any `Activity`.  Just add it in the layout like you would any other `View`.  Then create a custom `Adapter` from `BaseAdapter` and you're all set.  Just do a search for "Android Custom Adapter" and you'll find a ton of references that should help you out.